# What is the advantages of finding Maximal Frequent Itemsets

Tags: data-mining

I am searching for association rule mining in data mining. There are three type of frequent itemsets,

1. Frequent Itemsets
2. Closed Frequent Itemsets
3. Maximal Frequent Itemsets

To generate the association rules, we should to use frequent itemsets or closed frequent itemsets (The frequent itemsets can be found with closed frequent itemsets).

There is many algorithm to finding maximal frequent itemsets (MAFIA, Max-Miner, Depth Project, GenMax ...)

What is the advantages of finding maximal frequent itemsets? What is the main idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is that when looking for *long* itemsets with *low* support, you will end up exhausting all your memory with frequent but not interesting, redundant, and short itemsets.

To experience this, get some *large, real data* and run itemset mining on that; not the toy examples used in lectures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maximal itemsets are generally so closed to minimum support value because their definition requires that. I think it's not powerful way to generating rules with maximal frequent itemset because their support value is close to minimum support. what kind of itemsets generally use for rule generation? Frequent, closed Frequent or Maximal Frequent?

Comment: Higher support does not make the rules that much more interesting or reliable. Use secondary measures for that (or simply choose a higher minimum support).

Comment: you right, thanks. Some of secondary measures are covariance and lift, aren't they?

Comment: when you say large here ("get some large, real data ") - what sort of size are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

when size of dataset & number of frequent itemset in data set is huge, finding all frequent itemset is infeasible.  the Advantage of finding Maximal frequent itemset(MFI) over Frequent Itemset is (FI) is,

- All MFI can be generated before finding all FI.
- Once we find maximal frequent itemset , we can generate all frequent itemset in a single scan. Because every subset of frequent itemset is frequent.